# mysql how to select from one table if the second table has no matching information

Tags: mysql

I am trying to only show results from table inventoryfolders if the id does not exist in table newlisting.

Here is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM avirobust.inventoryfolders  
         WHERE parentFolderID = '".$foname."' 
           AND agentID = '".$mne."' 
           AND parentFolderID NOT IN (SELECT folderID FROM marketplace.newlisting)";
```

However it never returns a result even if newlisting has no data in it.

I know that join can work but can I use something like in my query above? If so what did I do wrong in my query?

Comment: you need to use your programming language for conditionals and check to see if the result does not return grater than 0.

Comment: Your query should work as you've written it. Can you post some sample data and the result you expect to get?

Comment: this part of the code is not working AND parentFolderID NOT IN (SELECT folderID FROM marketplace.newlisting)";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use this code

`SELECT inventoryfolders.* 
FROM avirobust.inventoryfolders LEFT JOIN marketplace.newlisting on (inventoryfolders.parentFolderID = newlisting.folderID)
WHERE parentFolderID = '".$foname."' 
AND agentID = '".$mne."'
AND newlisting.folderID is NULL`

It will return all records from inventoryfolders where no corresponding rows in newlisting